# Issue of installing tensorflow 1.15 with python 3.7.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am trying to install tensorflow 1.15, and it's installed well. When I run again `pip install tensorflow==1.15` it shows me the below screen:

```
C:\Users\Fatima>pip install tensorflow==1.15
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==1.15 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.37.1)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.2.2 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (3.15.8)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (0.36.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.15) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow==1.15) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow==1.15) (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow==1.15) (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow==1.15) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow==1.15) (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from h5py->keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow==1.15) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow==1.15) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\Fatima\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0->tensorflow==1.15) (3.4.1)
```

That means that tensorflow is installed, right?   The python I am using is `V3.7.7`

I use Pycharm to run the following code as test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

It gives me an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python394/for_trials.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

It's like it couldn't identify the tensorflow, or the python is not compatible with Tf1. However, following the guide, that python 3.7 and older are compatible with Tf1.

Could you please help me in solving that issue to install Tf1 ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that tensorflow is well installed in your machine but in which environment? for pycharm to see tensorflow, tensorflow must be installed in the same environment that pycharm uses to execute code. But if for example your pycharm is configured to execute codes in a virtual environment and tensorflow is installed in anaconda, there is has no way it works. So the simple solution that you can do is to change the environment of pycham to the environment where tensorflow is installed

Comment: Yes, I have notices that the installed Anacoona is python V3.8 ,  but where can I get the anaconda of python 3.7. I couldn't get it online.    When I click here one download, https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual   I get only Anaconda for python 3.8

Comment: why do you want to use anaconda for python 3.7? version 3.8 is good. You install version 3.8 and in pycharm you change the interpreter version like this:why do you want to use anaconda for python 3.7? version 3.8 is good. You install version 3.8 and in pycharm you change the version of the interpreter like this :( I can't add screenshots on the answer so I put it on another answer)

Comment: Yes, but when I go to install the tensorflow 1.15  from anaconda, it rejects. it gives an error that version of tensorflow must be 2.2 and up. for that I am looking for  anaconda for python 3.7

Comment: dans ce cas tu retrograde simplement la version de python comme : conda install python 3.7

Comment: oui, je suis entrain mtn d'installer le anaconda pr python 3.7, je vais voir s'lle va etre bien ou non

Comment: très bien , tu me tiendra au courant

Comment: oui, c march bien mtn ... j'ai installe le anaconda pr python 3.7, et mtn tt va b1

Answer (score 0):

[image: tu change l’interpréteur comme ceci]
tu change l’interpréteur comme ceci

tu change l’interpréteur comme ceci
tu change l’interpréteur comme ceci